# This question concerns blocks of consecutive integers whose sum divides the sum of the corresponding cubes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I conjecture this:

Extract from the consecutive positive integers the 'blocks' (1 to n), (2n+1 to 3n), (4n+1 to 5n), ... Then the sum of the integers in alternating blocks divides the sum of the cubes of the same integers; in LaTeX: \sum_{s=0}{s=k}{\sum_{i=1}{i=n}{(2sn+i)}} divides \sum_{s=0}{s=k}{\sum_{s=0}{s=k}{\sum_{i=1}{i=n}{(2sn+i)^3}}

but have failed to prove it. I've used the familiar identities sum of first n cubes equals square of nth triangular number, $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. (The second has got me halfway there by pairing cubes symmetrically.)

Comment: Doesn't this divisibility property work for *any* starting and ending points, not just $2kn+1$ to $(2k+1)n$? Hint: the sum of the integers from $A+1$ to $B$ is (sum of integers up to $B$) minus (sum of integers up to $A$), and similarly for sums of cubes.

Comment: I'm sorry: what I should have written was 'The sum of the integers in all the (alternating) blocks - note one block - divides the sum of the corresponding cubes'.

Comment: I meant 'not' one block - sorry again. What I meant was: sum(s=0 to k) sum(i=1 to n) (2sn+i) divides sum(s=0 to k) sum (i=1 to n) (2sn+i)^3. I suspect the result goes for all odd powers.

Comment: In that case, it's best to edit that clarification directly into the question (in LaTeX so that it is easy for others to read).

Comment: \sum_{s=0}{s=k}{\sum_{i=1}{i=n}{(2sn+i)}} divides \sum_{s=0}{s=k}{\sum_{s=0}{s=k}{\sum_{i=1}{i=n}{(2sn+i)^3}}

Comment: Paul Stephenson, please edit the original question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that $\sum_{i=1}^k i=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k i^3=\left(\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right)^2$

Pursuant to Greg Martin's comment, $$\sum_{i=m+1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$
and $$\sum_{i=m+1}^n i^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\right)^2 \\=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\right)\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\right)$$
The sum of the consecutive cubes plainly has as a factor the sum of the consecutive integers, QED.

Comment: See clarification in LaTeX above.

Comment: LaTeX form now entered in original question.

Comment: I even think that the blocks and the gaps can be of two different lengths: this is certainly true for blocks of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

Original conjecture for cubes and equal spaces and blocks true: I at last organised the algebra tidily. I only needed the triangular number identity, the sum of squares identity and the sum of cubes identity.